# Are there any computer science encyclopedias?

Tags: reference-request, books

Consider the volume "The Princeton Companion to Mathematics" which has the broadest range of topics attempted by any book in the field.

Does a Computer Science counterpart exist?

Comment: We don't have a strict policy for list questions, but there is a [general dislike](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). Please note also [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/20) and [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/145/) discussion; you might want to improve your question as to avoid the problems explained there. If you are not sure how to improve your question maybe we can help you in [chat]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two that I've seen:

- [Encyclopedia of Computer Science and Technology by Allen Kent](https://www.amazon.com/s/?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=Encyclopedia+of+Computer+Science+and+Technology+kent) (Over 40 volumes)
- [Encyclopedia of Computer Science and Technology by Harry Henderson](https://www.e-reading.club/bookreader.php/135785/Encyclopedia_of_Computer_Science_and_Technology.pdf)

Also, Wikipedia could be considered containing a [CS encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_computer_science).